# Terminal type programs

Tags: command-line, networking

I am looking for a terminal type program so I can connect via Console / Telnet / SSH into Cisco devices.
Does "Terminal" offer this ability or do I need something else (such as PuTTY)?

Comment: Please take a look at this tutorial:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/secure-shell-ssh/212142-Configure-SSH-on-Tty-Lines-with-Menu-Opt.html

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? How have you"looked"?

Comment: When you connect with SSH to Cisco (or other equipment / servers) you get a CLI, Command Line Interface, which is a terminal like interface. What do you need more ?

Comment: Have you tried `ssh` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available for serial console connections  - the easiest is probably `putty`, but I also enjoy `minicom` for a nice CLI-only option.

You might be able to find some others here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators

Of course, if you are using SSH instead of the serial console, there is always `ssh`